# Media Queries Height Pag css

Tags: css, media-queries

@media screen and (min-width: 799px) and (max-width: 800px) {
}

I have a website whose resolution is 800x600 and another 800x400. The width is always the same, but not the height. How can I make the height of the page 600 in one and 400 in another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-height` in media queries to make a website responsive for height

1 use comma for different rule

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px), 
   screen and (max-height: 700px) {
   ...
}
```

2.using and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px)and (max-height: 700px) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign different hight with this code

```
@media (min-height: 400px) and (max-height: 600px) and (min-width: 799px) and (max-width: 800px) { ... }
```